# Disable smooth transition when using findnext in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using `findallasync()` and `findnext()` in WebView in my android app. When `findnext()` is calling, webview starts scroll to find word. This scrolling is smooth and slow. It there are any ways to disable smooth scrolling and scroll to finded word instanly?

Comment: Did you ever find out how? I need to do this too at this point :(

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not find a solution

Comment: I am needing this as well... any luck?

Comment: @grovin please star the following issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1064856

Comment: @efemoney please star the following issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1064856

Comment: @DanielRust ok, starred on this. Still waiting for a solution.